# Different Object of same type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a class

> CartIndexViewModel

in my project SportsStore. I am making calls to WCF service so I want to pass an Object of CartIndexViewModel so I copied the required .dll files in the WCF Project but its conflicting as it says there is a type mismatch.

> SportsStore.WebUI.ServiceReference.CartIndexViewModel
>   SportsStore.WebUI.Models.CartIndexViewModel

both the classes are same, have same properties and methods but in different project how can i pass an object from sending side i.e SportsStore.WebUI.Models.CartIndexViewModel and the receiving end 
i.e. SportsStore.WebUI.ServiceReference.CartIndexViewModel receive the object.
I dont have much knowledge i tried doing a lot of homework on this but couldn't get a solution.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First add a reference to the library, then generate the service reference. Make sure "Reuse types" is checked.

Comment: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:cart. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_5AF3E0DD8BC6C07DB82D1311023900142DAAF627A4D16C9BF724C68146C303C3' with data contract name 'Product_5AF3E0DD8BC6C07DB82D1311023900142DAAF627A4D16C9BF724C68146C303C3:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to

Comment: the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.